# Summation of series of first $2n$ natural numbers and first $3n$ natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having an issue understanding the concept of the sum of the first $2n$ and $3n$ natural numbers.

So as I have gathered, the sum of the first $2n$ natural numbers is $n(2n+1)$, and the sum of the first $3n$ natural numbers is $(3n(3n+1))/2$.

But this is what is confusing me, $2n$ implies that it is $2+4+6 + \ldots$ or does it mean $2$ lots of natural numbers. It is really the way it worded is confusing me.

Comment: Could you write the question exactly as it's worded?  That might help decipher it.

Comment: $1+2+\ldots+2n$

Answer (score 2):

$1+2+3+\dots + n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so $1+2+3+\dots+2n=\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2}=n(2n+1).$

In the same fashion, $1+2+3+\dots+3n=\frac{3n(3n+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure, whet you're asking but I'll give a shot answering. Just to remind you, the formula for the sum of $n$ natural numbers is

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

The formulae you gave seem to be for summing natural numbers **up to** $2n$ and $3n$. I.e. you just substitute $2n$ to the equation above to get the formulae you were talking about.

$$1+2+\ldots + 2n = \frac{(2n)(2n+1)}{2} =n(2n+1)$$

---

If you instead want to find the sum of first $n$ even numbers you do the following

$$\sum_{i=1}^n 2i = 2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n i = 2(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}) = n(n+1)$$

So for example the sum of first five even numbers is

$$2+4+6+8+10 = 5(5+1)=5\cdot6=30$$

I let you figure out how it works for $\sum_{i=1}^n 3i$.